# Undefined control sequence in edef (with polynom)

Tags: errors, undefined, compilation-error, polynom

For some reason, this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{polynom}

\newcommand{\calcRatFunc}[1]{
    \edef\tmp{\polyfactorize{#1}} % The only difference
}

\begin{document}
    \calcRatFunc{x^2 + x - 2}
\end{document}
```

gives an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pld@GetPoly #1#2->\def \pld@pool 
                                  {#1}\def \pld@aftermacro {#2}\pld@GetPoly@ 
l.10     \calcRatFunc{x^2 + x - 2}
```

but this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{polynom}

\newcommand{\calcRatFunc}[1]{
    \polyfactorize{#1} % The only difference
}

\begin{document}
    \calcRatFunc{x^2 + x - 2}
\end{document}
```

compiles fine ... into an empty document. (`test.dvi PS 69x13 69x13+0+0 16-bit sRGB 513B 0.000u 0:00.000`.)

Full error output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 11 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2015/07/15 v1.2 Class to compile TeX sub-files stand
alone
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polynom/polynom.sty) (./test.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
\pld@GetPoly #1#2->\def \pld@pool 
                                  {#1}\def \pld@aftermacro {#2}\pld@GetPoly@ 
l.10     \calcRatFunc{x^2 + x - 2}

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

My goal is to perform calculations on polynomials without unnecessarily repeating calculations or LaTeX code (to calculate properties of rational functions). [Full code in 2019-1-3.bac.tex.](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5c02d83082bd1c0ae4de24fd)

Comment: most latex commands may not be used in `\edef`, what do you want it to do here?

Comment: I added a clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most latex commands can not be used inside `\edef`. Clearly, the commands of this package do not work by expansion and can not be made to do anything sensible in `\edef`.

To see why you get the error consider

```
\def\tmp{\def\zzz{abc}}
```

that defines `\tmp` so that if executed it defines `\zzz` to be `abc` but

```
\edef\tmp{\def\zzz{abc}}
```

`\edef` expands token by token without doing any assignments, so `\def` expands to `\def` then `\zzz` expands, or at least would expand, but as it has no definition you get an undefined control sequence error.

Comment: Is it possible to use `\noexpand` to get it to work? Or is there a better way to reuse the result of `\polyfactorize`?